# Frey's elliptic curve and perfect numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, perfect-numbers

Let $E_n:y^2=x(x-\sigma(n)/2)(x+\sigma(n)/n)$ be a Frey-elliptic curve, where $\sigma$ denotes the sum of divisors of the natural number $n$.

If $n$ is a perfect number ($\sigma(n)=2n$) then the $j$-invariant is given by:

$$j(n) = \frac{16^2(n^2+2n+4)^3}{(2n)^2(n+2)^2}$$

If $n$ is a perfect number, then the points $(n:0:1),(-2:0:1)$ are integral points of $E_n$.

What properties does this curve have, if $n$ is an (odd) perfect number?

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting. If $n$ is a perfect number then this curve has three rational 2-torsion points, and that’s about as much as anyone can say. Remember that the original Frey curve is useful for Fermat because if a non-trivial counterexample to FLT exists, then the curve is not modular, which would contradict the modularity theorem. I don’t think this curve can be shown to not be modular.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Doesn't it have three rational 2-torsion points for any $n>0$? For perfect numbers those are moreover integral, but it is not an equivalenr condition.

Comment: One thing to note is that this elliptic curve has discriminant $(\sigma(n)/2\cdot\sigma(n)/n\cdot\sigma(n)(1/2+1/n))^2$, so that this curve's properties rely on the factorization of not only $n$ and $\sigma(n)$, but also $n+2$. I doubt perfectness of $n$ will be enough to guarantee the curve to have interesting properties.